# Inserting duplicate values into a table using $wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have a table named `wp_q33uds_campaign` in my MySQL database, which is defined using a plugin as follows:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `$tablename`(
            `user_id` INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `tweet1` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            `date1` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            `tweet2` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            `date2` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            `tweet3` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            `date3` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            `tweet4` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            `date4` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            `tweet5` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            `date5` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            `flag` INT(10) NOT NULL,
            `created` DATETIME,
            );";
```

Now, I want the same user to be able to insert multiple entries into the table ie multiple entries of the same `user_id` should be allowed to be inserted into the table.

The code for inserting values into the table:

```
if($_POST['submitted'])
{
     $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."campaign";

        $new_data = array(
                'user_id' => 4344,
                'tweet1' => $_POST['tweet1'],
                'date1' => strtotime($_POST['date1']) - 19800,
                'tweet2' => $_POST['tweet2'],
                'date2' => strtotime($_POST['date2']) - 19800,
                'tweet3' => $_POST['tweet3'],
                'date3' => strtotime($_POST['date3']) - 19800,
                'tweet4' => $_POST['tweet4'],
                'date4' => strtotime($_POST['date4']) - 19800,
                'tweet5' => $_POST['tweet5'],
                'date5' => strtotime($_POST['date5']) - 19800,
                'flag' => 1,
                'created' => current_time('mysql'),
            );
        //print_r($new_data);

        $wpdb->insert($table_name, $new_data);
}
```

However, the `wp_q33uds_campaign` table doesn't accept entries with an `user_id` already present in the table. THe table does accept entries with `user_id` not present in the table.

How can I allow my table to accept entries with a duplicate `user_id`?

Comment: Don't set it to auto increment

Comment: Examples like the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32366677/1816093 I am sorry it is not immediately tailored on your behalf, but it is possible

Comment: @Flyer That doesn't seem to help solve my problem.

Comment: but what @Flyer said makes sense to me in the face of it all. An auto_inc requires it to be PK . Nope, requires it to be a key. I am wrong again.

Comment: @Drew I have auto increment disabled, and there are no primary keys in the table. And yet, I can't seem to insert entries with `user_id` already present in the table.

Comment: by the way, I would always have a pk in the table, even if it is a throwaway column you don't care about. You point a reporting tool at it without one, it is one sad experience.